# How to get boostrap content to be enclosed in two column with the browser's height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollbar

I'm having a problem that seems pretty common but with a slight twist.

I'm using bootstrap for my web application. The main layout/master page has a top bar (for actions) and a left side navigation bar (for navigation between the pages of the application, of course). So, the page's content is always in the "bottom-right" part of the screen (if I can say, although that "bottom-right" cover about 80% of the screen).

Now, for one page only, I want the content to be enclosed in a two column layout with independent scroll bars. On the left side, I want to display a task list and on the right side, I want to display boxes (two boxes wide) for my employees with their already assigned tasks. I want to be able to navigate in my task list independently from my employees list.

Here is a very basic mock-up (I know, it's ugly) of what I'm trying to accomplish : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwbWwcCjL9EJT1B5MlFMQVh0UnM/view?usp=sharing

Is it even possible to accomplish this when bootstrap is involved? Right now, my task list and my employees list extend on many page length (4-5 at least). I want them to be contained within the browser window and have an independent scroll bar for each list so I can drag a task from the top of the list to the bottom employee (as an example), which is now impossible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found a solution. I had tried to use the "scroll" class, but I had forgotten to use a "max-height". Now, I use the following code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ResizeListsSoTheyFitInScreen();
});
$(window).resize(function () { ResizeListsSoTheyFitInScreen(); });

function ResizeListsSoTheyFitInScreen() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var taskListTop = $('#TaskList').offset().top;
    $('#TaskList').css('max-height', (windowHeight - taskListTop) + 'px');
    var employeeListTop = $('#EmployeeList').offset().top;
    $('#EmployeeList').css('max-height', (windowHeight - employeeListTop) + 'px');
}
```

It works fine, though I'm not 100% sure it's the best solution because I have to account for the bottom margin and such on my own. If you have a better solution, I'm open to it.

Thanks a lot